# Redirect to action/page LightVC PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, model-view-controller, authentication

In a nutshell I'm trying to log in to my website and show a different page after success. The flow is the user fills out the form and submits, I use jquery $.post() to post the data to a controller's actionLogin. Then in actionLogin, I verify the user and redirect to another page using `header('dashboard/1')` where dashboard is another action in the same controller and 1 is the id of the user. My problem is that the page from actionDashboard does not actually render. The user is stuck on the login page and I'm only getting the Dashboard's view code in my jquery $.post response, so I can see it in the console when I log it. Any Ideas? I'm using [LightVC](http://lightvc.org). Here's the simplified code below:

**main.js**

```
$.post('/default/ajaxLogin', {
    email: $('#email').val(), 
    pass: $('#pass').val()
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**default.php (controller)**

```
//we start here where we can use main.js
public function actionIndex() 
{
    $this->setLayout('default');
    $this->setLayoutVar('pageTitle', 'Home');
}    
public function actionAjaxLogin() 
{ 
    //do some login verification
    //ok login successful, now redirect to dashboard
    header('Location: /dashboard/1');
}
public function actionDashboard($userId)
{
    $this->setLayout('dashboard');
    $this->setLayoutVar('pageTitle', 'Dashboard');
    $this->loadView('default/dashboard');
}
```

Like I said, for some reason, the page doesn't actually render. I only get the html back in main.js's response. I've seen a bunch of ideas from other questions involving Yii and Laravel but nothing with my specific issue or LightVC framework. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel as you are using the Ajax post and expecting it to redirect to a different page, it seems not possible as ajax requests expect response back and do process in the callbacks on the client side.

I think you should try removing the header line of code and only render the dashboard layout.

You can try below modified code and see

```
//we start here where we can use main.js
public function actionIndex() 
{
    $this->setLayout('default');
    $this->setLayoutVar('pageTitle', 'Home');
}    
public function actionAjaxLogin() 
{ 
    //do some login verification
    //ok login successful, now redirect to dashboard
    $this->actionDashboard(1);
    //header('Location: /dashboard/1');
}
public function actionDashboard($userId)
{
    $this->setLayout('dashboard');
    $this->setLayoutVar('pageTitle', 'Dashboard');
    $this->loadView('default/dashboard');
}
```

Comment: I tried calling the action like you stated but it gives the same result. I believe you may be right with ajax not being able to do this. I may just have to do a regular submit and see what happens. I will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, plz let me know and update me for any further help... :)

Comment: It works! Thanks for your help! Just to recap for any others out there, using $.post to submit while in an MVC framework does not allow you to redirect to a different page because it basically demands a response and intercepts the html. Thus, it doesn't allow the page to actually change.